# Unable to connect to Postgres Docker container from application server

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a Postgres image running my database and I run this as a Docker container and I can connect to it from psql, but when I connect to it from my application server, I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:342)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at doobie.util.transactor$Transactor$FromDriverManagerUnapplied.$anonfun$apply$19(transactor.scala:378)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at doobie.util.transactor$Transactor$FromDriverManagerUnapplied.$anonfun$create$2(transactor.scala:347)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at blocking @ doobie.util.transactor$Transactor$FromDriverManagerUnapplied.$anonfun$create$1(transactor.scala:347)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at fromAutoCloseable @ doobie.util.transactor$Transactor$FromDriverManagerUnapplied.$anonfun$create$1(transactor.scala:347)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at fromAutoCloseable @ doobie.util.transactor$Transactor$FromDriverManagerUnapplied.$anonfun$create$1(transactor.scala:347)
cpo-platform-server-cpo-platform-1  |   at use @ doobie.util.transactor$Transactor$$anon$4.apply(transactor.scala:164)
```

Is there anything that I have to watch out for when connecting from one Docker container where my application server is running to another Docker container where my database is running? I use the docker compose to start both of them like this:

```
services:
  my-app:
    image: me/my-app-server:1.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9000:9000
    environment:
      configEnv: test

  my-db:
    image: my-db-postgres-test-container
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
```

After starting, I can connect to the database using psql, but connecting via my application server fails. The credentials, database server etc., are all correctly configured, but still it won't connect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have two containers started, exposed ports for the host are not exposed across containers.

Use the hostname of the postgres container, `my-db` in your case, instead of localhost, to connect from `my-app`.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  This is one of the big benefits of docker - your application and other containers are networked together "naturally" without fear of port conflicts between them.  (docker-compose puts all its containers in a single docker network by default)